# Downloading 32 bit iOS Apps for 32 bit iPhones after iOS 11 is released

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, 32-bit

I have a 32-bit iPhone.  I understand that 32 bit iPhones will no longer be supported by iOS 11.

Will I be able to download and buy 32 bit apps from the store for iPhones running 32-bit iOS versions (ie iOS 10.x) after iOS 11 is released?

In other words, is Apple removing 32bit apps from the store completely or just removing them for iOS 11 devices?

Answer (score 4):

While Apple is moving to 64-bit apps on the App Store, that doesn't mean they're 64-bit only apps. In fact any new apps published since 1 February 2015 has had to support 64-bit. This is also the case for any updates to existing apps (i.e. they also must be 64-bit compatible).

In other words, any 32-bit only apps submitted to Apple will be rejected, but if that same app also supports 64-bit, then it'll be available for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of iOS etc.

In summary, any app that:

- is only 32-bit is on borrowed time
- is only 64-bit is fine
- that supports both 32-bit and 64-bit will be fine

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11 will not support the apps because they are removing the architecture support from the OS. Apple is not changing the store. In the future you may find 32bit versions to be unavailable due to applications dropping support for older architectures however this isn't because Apple is forcing them but because they see it as unimportant